# How do you handle URL Jumping?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url-routing

I've been reviewing the amount times users visiting our site go to the address bar and either select another previously seen address on our site or type in an address they already know exists our site. I don't think everybody is trying to attack us, but they are trying to navigate through complicated pages for their own ends.

I've coined this in our team as URL Jumping, this may well be wrong but its helped us keeping on topic.

We're work with ASP.Net Version 4.0 VB.Net

I found very little information out there about how to handle this using standard proceedures, and even less from our third party server application suppliers.

I've found that when URL Jumping, the landing page from the jump will have no information about the URL Referer -

> If IsNothing(Request.UrlReferrer) = True Then...

So this has given me a hook in to handling the problem.

Because there are times when I don't mind the user jumping around, I've provided them with the ability to jump across pages where its okay. I've also developed a solution by checking the database values expected from those pages once processed, but this is not full proof.

Does anyone know of built-in handling from ASP.Net? Or is this the type of issue where you have no choice but to handle by checking for expected database values?

Comment: I don't know why you shouldn't allow users to do this?

Comment: This is completely normal behavior of users.  If you are having an issue where people can access data anonymously when they shouldn't, then you need to fix your page security.

Comment: *"they are trying to navigate through complicated pages for their own ends"* < this is like the whole idea of the internet (and it sounds like you are trying to break it). When is this an issue?

Comment: I did struggle to find the right way to put this without making it an essay... 100% I agree with both Macron and David.

Comment: The issue is that the users are required to fill in various fields on each page to progress to the next page. I could put everything on one page, but 50 plus questions on a page is a bit much eh!

Comment: Yeah, there are times where this is an issue, if they are following a long process in your application for example, or jump to the middle. You could set and check session, and if they land on a page, redirect them to the beginning of the process for example if Session value isn't set. You could also use a unique Token in the query string on pages that they are not supposed to just access via URL. If its wrong, once again redirect to correct area.

Comment: So I am allowing users to jump between pages if they've provided enough information for us to process their needs. If not I push them back to the latest point we can handle and request them to proceed from there. Hopefully its more understood now that I'm not trying to break the internet, or ruin the whole user experience, but I do really appreciate you guys taking a look and being honest about how you feel about the user experience too. So the short version of the initial question was to ask if anyone knows of ways to validate pages the visitor is not actually on using asp.net?

Comment: Thanks Dylan, I had considered the Session approach, however the user may be logged in (sorry I hadn't mentioned this before.. concerned about giving too much information) So they could be in a situation where they've already filled in the required information then returned at a later date, if they want to edit the details they will be sent to page 1, but may then want to jump to page 5, I'd like them to be able to do this provided pages 1-4 are all completed satisfactorally.

Comment: I would handle this with a DB call on page load, have a field that designates the maximum page they could access and if the page request is <= to that allow, if not force them to the page required.  Session could also be used depending on how long between accesses users will have.  You could also use a cookie to do this, although again it would depend on how long between accesses.

Comment: Thanks Macron, as stated above this is pretty much what I'm doing at the moment, so appreciate the confirmation of my approach, but is there no way asp.net can support this? I do appreciate its a tall ask, hence the reason coming here to ask in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Having seen the responses from other members who's credentials stand up for themselves and based on several days of deep searches around the web myself I see no clear asp.net standard handling which resolves the issue of URL Jumping. AS has been suggested by others here I have stuck with, and expanded my own solution.

In Page_Load of the landing page after the call

```
 If Not Page.IsPostBack Then 
     ...
 End If
```

I put

```
 If (Session("IsFirstTime") Is Nothing OrElse Session("IsFirstTime") <> True) Then
     Session("IsFirstTime") = True 
 End If
```

But at the very start of Page_Load I use a check for the URLReferrer, if this returns Nothing I check the session variable

```
 If IsNothing(Request.UrlReferrer) = True Then
      If IsNothing(Session("IsFirstTime")) = False Then
          ...
      End If
 End If
```

Within this code block, which is used on all pages, I make a call into each page in the order it should be called to check if all the database fields are occupied as required.

```
 Dim pageOne As PageOne = New PageOne()
 If pageOne.PageContinuity = False Then
     MyBase.ResponseRedirect("~/PageOne.aspx")
 Else
     Dim pageTwo As PageTwo = New PageTwo()
     If pageTwo.PageContinuity = False Then
         'PreviousPageNavigation(sender, e)
         MyBase.ResponseRedirect("~/PageTwo.aspx")
     Else
         ...
```

Whichever page returns false is the page the user will land at, I use a message on the page hit to advise the user that using the webpage controls to progress is the safest solution, but still allow them to continue, allowing for user freedom as suggested in the initial responses to my question.

```
 Public Function PageContinuity()
     Try
         Dim cv = New CustomValidator
         If PolicyHelper.GetDataSetValue("xxx") = "0" Then
             cv.IsValid = False
         End If
         If cv.IsValid = True Then
             If PolicyHelper.GetDataSetValue("xxx") = "0" Then
                 cv.IsValid = False
             End If
         Else
             Return cv.IsValid
         End If

         Return cv.IsValid

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
 End Function
```

I shall also look at setting a session variable to the page I've identified to load so should the user make a screen refresh then the page will load as normal rather than carrying out checks on all pages prior to this one in the chain.